# Unable to run AXIOS get Request using a secure server(HTTPS) from Android react native app

Tags: react-native, https, axios

I've been trying to run requests using AXIOS as part of my react native app.
Here is my code snippet:

```
const response = await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: this.url('https://my-domain:5000/api/v1/version'),
                signal: this.newAbortSignal(5000),
                //headers: this.headers
            })
```

My abort signal function:

```
newAbortSignal(timeoutMs: number) {
        const abortController = new AbortController();
        setTimeout(() => abortController.abort(), timeoutMs || 0);
      
        return abortController.signal;
    }
```

The domain is trusted CA and verified so the https requests should work.
I also tried going to that endpoint manually from the device and it works perfectly fine from the browser.
I've defined no headers on purpose in order to exclude a cors issue.
I am receiving a ERR_NETWORK status code from AXIOS.
On the Server side I am not even receiving any incoming requests, like it never leaves the phone.

I tried this on both debug mode on a physical device and also a signed APK release version on the same device and both do not work.

Another attempt I tried just running a get request to 'https://google.com' and it failed with ERR_CANCELLED which I am not sure what that means.

FYI I also tried node fetch and it didn't work as well.
I'd really appreciate some help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 2 problems that prevented from my code to work.

First issue was that I incorrectly signed my Express server.
When signing your express server make sure you use your key, crt, and ca-bundle files.

```
const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.crt', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/ca.ca-bundle', 'utf8');
const credentials: https.ServerOptions = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca};
https
    .createServer(credentials, app)
    ...
    ...
```

My second issue was the way I used Axios that prevented this from working.
For some reason creating an axios client and then using it as following:

```
const client = new Axios(..)
await client.get(....)
```

It returned some weird behavior throwing some unexplained android exception about a Double not being able to be null.

When I moved to using:

```
const response = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '...',
  ...
})
```

It worked fine.